# What is the incorrect pivot table logic?

Tags: excel, excel-pivot

In an excel pivot table, I am looking to count all items created after the exit date for projects.  None of the formulas have worked in the calculated field section.Several attempts listed below.

Projects is the Row Label.  The calculated fields below were attempts to count the items created after exit per project.

- ='Created On'>'Exit Date'
- ='Created On'>'Exit Date'
- =COUNT('Created On' >'Exit Date' )
- = IF('Created On' >'Exit Date', 1, 0)

Here is a sample of the data:

```
Item Type     Created On        Project     Exit Date
Issue          12/12/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Risk           11/01/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Issue          12/14/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Risk           10/12/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Risk           10/30/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Issue          11/14/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Risk           10/13/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Risk           12/01/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Bug            10/11/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Risk           10/10/17           ABC       10/6/2017
Risk           11/06/17           ABC       10/6/2017
```

Comment: Needs sample data and expected results.

Comment: Added information above.  Thank you

Comment: The expected results from the calculated field is the item count if the created on date is after the exit date.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: =countif(b:b,">"&d:d)

Comment: =countif( 'Created On' ,">"& 'Exit Date') this formula displays an error in the calculated field section.

Comment: Is this unable to be done? I have not found a solution after much research.